# Building a list with loops

Tags: list, loops, lisp, common-lisp, cons

We just covered loops today in class and I've got a few things I need to do. Put simply, I have to build a list using loops instead of recursion. I seem to be at a stumbling block here. For this example, we need to do a simple countdown. The function takes an argument and then returns a list of all the positive integers less than or equal to the initial argument. (countdown 5) => (5 4 3 2 1)

I'm having a hard time getting loops for whatever reason. The ones we talked about was Loop, Do, Dotimes, and Dolist. I've tried this with a couple loops and always end up with a similar result.

```
(defun countdown (num)
  (cond ((= num 0) nil)
        (T  (let* ((list nil))
              (loop
                (if (= num 0) (return list)
                    (setf list (cons list num)))
                (setf num (- num 1)))))))
```

My output shows up like this:

```
(((((NIL . 5) . 4) . 3) . 2) .1)
```

*update:* I've solved the issue. Apparently I needed to reverse the order in the `cons`, so `num` comes before `list`. Does anyone care to explain this? I thought you put the list first and then what you put second would be added to the end of it. At least, that's how I've been using it so far without issue.

Answer (score 4):

### Reverse the arguments to `cons` (and why)

You wrote in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25882231/1281433) (that, since it asks for more information, perhaps should have been a comment):

> I've solved the issue. Apparently I needed to reverse the order in the
>   cons, so num comes before list. Does anyone care to explain this? I
>   thought you put the list first and then what you put second would be
>   added to the end of it. At least, that's how I've been using it so far
>   without issue.

The function is documented in the HyperSpec clearly: [*Function* **CONS**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons.htm).  The examples in the documentation show, e.g.,

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))) =>  (1 2 3 4)
(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '()))) =>  (A B C)
(cons 'a '(b c d)) =>  (A B C D)
```

and even the note

> If object-2 is a list, cons can be thought of as producing a new list which is like it but has object-1 prepended.

It may help to read through [14.1.2 Conses as Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_ab.htm), as well, which includes:

> A list is a chain of conses in which the car of each cons is an element of the list, and the cdr of each cons is either the next link in the chain or a terminating atom.

### Concerning `loop`

Many of the answers here are pointing out to you that the **loop** form includes a special iteration language.  That's true, but it can also be used in the way that you're using it.  That way is called a *simple loop*:

> #### [6.1.1.1.1 Simple Loop](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_aaaa.htm)
>
> A simple loop form is one that has a body containing only compound
>   forms. Each form is evaluated in turn from left to right. When the
>   last form has been evaluated, then the first form is evaluated again,
>   and so on, in a never-ending cycle. A simple loop form establishes an
>   implicit block named nil. The execution of a simple loop can be
>   terminated by explicitly transfering control to the implicit block
>   (using return or return-from) or to some exit point outside of the
>   block (e.g., using throw, go, or return-from).

Simple loops probably aren't as common as loops using the nicer features that loop provides, but if you just covered this in class, you might not be there yet.  The other answers do provide some good examples, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you speaking about common lisp [loop](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm), your countdown may look like this:

```
(defun countdown (from-number)
  (loop :for x :from from-number :downto 1 :collect x)) 

CL-USER> (countdown 10) 
(10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: OP's loop is OK, though (except that the args to cons are reversed). OP just used the [6.1.1.1.1 Simple Loop](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_aaaa.htm). Since "[OP] just covered loops today in class", it may be that they only used those, so far.

Answer (score 1):

Using `loop`, which has its own "special-purpose language" that does not really look like Lisp:

```
(defun countdown (n)
  (loop
    for i from n downto 1
    collect i))
```

Or using `do`:

```
(defun countdown (n)
  (do ((i 1 (1+ i)) 
       (res nil (cons i res)))
      ((> i n) res)))
```

See [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), especially chapters 7 and 22.

Comment: OP's loop is OK, though (except that the args to cons are reversed). OP just used the [6.1.1.1.1 Simple Loop](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_aaaa.htm). Since "[OP] just covered loops today in class", it may be that they only used those, so far.